# the meaning of "... let their hair down one last time..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Join us, Matt and Allison are tying the knot! take the plunge with them Saturday, June 22nd, at their Engagement/Beach Party, there'll be no chance to get cold feet at this sizzling hot summer party! takes place at Turtle Beach, this part is not stuffy ceremony, so join in **if you want to see the couple let their hair down one last time before the walk down the aisle** \ RSVP by Friday ,  June 15th, It'll be a blast"

I checked in the dictionary:
"let your hair down" means:  to enjoy yourself and start to relax, especially after working very hard

"go/walk down the aisle" means: to get married

but, I don't get the exact meaning of the sentence in bold.
in other words, I don't understand why they let their hair down one last time.
could you please explain it?

Comment: What exactly is confusing to you?  They're going to relax one last time before they get married.

Comment: What is confusing about **if you want to see the couple [enjoy themselves and start to relax] one last time before the walk down the aisle**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as the dictionary suggests.

> If you want to see the couple "relax and have fun" before they "get married"...

Getting married is a serious matter, the ceremony is serious and it implies a lifetime commitment. There is a notion that single people are freer to have fun. This invite just means that there will be the last relaxed and fun party that will be before the boring and "stuffy" ceremony, and before the couple's serious commitment to each other.